# excel sum column if value x is in column A or B and A does not equal B

Tags: excel, sum

I need to have a sum if function that would return all values where John is in column B and not in column A. So it should only return 50 for the below.

```
Column A     Column B           Column C 
John         John, Steve, Fred  100
Steve        John               50
Fred         Fred, Steve        150
```

Comment: SUMIFS with wildcards will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"<>*" & "John" & "*",B:B,"=*" & "John" & "*")
```

[image]

But that might lead to false positive like `Ann` will also see `Anne`.

To get around that you need to change to SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$1:$C$3,(ISERROR(SEARCH("," & "John" & ",","," & $A$1:$A$3 & ",")))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & "John" & ",","," & $B$1:$B$3 & ","))))
```

[image]